# Why does world start to fall apart and burn because of one's tapasya?

Tags: tapasya

Why does world start to fall apart and burn when one does intense tapasya? For instance,there's a story of Succhi in Yoga Vasistha who continues intense tapas for thousands of years so that Bhagawan Indra starts noticing her when the world starts to burn up because of her intense tapas.

> इति वर्षसहस्राणि साकरोद्दारुणं तपः ।
>  सप्तसप्तमहालोकसंतापकरमुन्मुखी
>   ॥ २७ ॥ 
>   **3.72.27** She continued for many thousand years in her austere devotion, to the great astonishment of fourteen (seven + seven) worlds, that got affrighted at her austerities.
>
> तस्याः कल्पाग्निभीमेन तपसा हि महागिरिः ।
>  बभूव तेन ज्वलितो जज्वालेव
>   ततो जगत् ॥ २८ ॥
>  **3.72.28** The great mountain was set in a blaze, by the
>   fervour of her devotion; and that flame spread to all the worlds, like
>   the blaze of a portentous meteor.

[Source](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-sanskrit/d/doc253414.html)

Comment: Have always wondered about this!